# trouble getting a specific element out of a 2D list in python

Tags: python, excel, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

So I'm trying to remove all elements of a 2D array taken from an excel sheet with one of a few headers.  values is the 2D array containing my data.  One of my main problems is that not all of the rows have anything in the last column which needs to be removed and results in alot of index out of bounds errors.  Note, the first dimension of the 2D array is rows.

```
badColumns = ['Queue', 'Subject', 'Risk', etc...] #Some other ones are here

for col in range(len(values[0])):
    for badText in badColumns:
        if badText in values[0][col]:
            for row in range(len(values)):
                try:
                    del values[row][col]
                except IndexError:
                    continue
```

Throwing print statements around the del statement shows no change with the del statement.  Any idea what might cause this?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why not just determine which columns you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're modifying the list as you work your way through it, which leads to problems. Based on what you've shared this doesn't explain all your problems but it should help.

Run this code as an example of what you're problem is; I'd be happy to help more if this doesn't make the problem clear:

```
#Bad Code:

a = range(6)
print a
for i in range(len(a)):
    try:
        del a[i]
    except IndexError:
        print 'Bad index', i
print a
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Bad index 3
Bad index 4
Bad index 5
[1, 3, 5]
```

This code is better: (well maybe? not very pythonic, but it works...)

```
a = range(6)
print a
for i in range(len(a))[::-1]: #the only difference is this reversal
    try:
        del a[i]
    except IndexError:
        print 'Bad index', i
print a
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[]
```

Here's what's happening in the bad code:

First, a = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

Then, i = 0

Now a[i] is deleted, so a = [1,2,3,4,5]

Then, i=1

Now a[i] is deleted, so **the element at index 1 is deleted, not index 0**

Thus, now a = [1,3,4,5] and you've skipped deleting the element "1"

Comment: This seems to be the source of the IndexOutofBounds, still trying to figure a way around modifying while you're traversing it.  How can I do this in such a way that I'm not doing that?

Comment: I'm not coming up with any good solutions right now... try using `[::-1]` in your original code and see if it helps

Comment: @avorum: Deleting or inserting in the middle of a sequence changes all of the following indices, which means you'll end up either skipping or repeating one of the elements. The way out of this is to iterate over the sequence backward, as the answer shows. Meanwhile, you can't actually modify a sequence while traversing it; you have to either modify the original while traversing a copy of the sequence, or build a copy while traversing the original (the latter is usually more Pythonic).

Comment: I can't decide whether to advise you to make copies (more pythonic) or to just delete elements (more efficient)... I can tell you that for debugging you should replace the `continue` with a print statement of some kind

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code.

First, you cannot modify a sequence while traversing it.*

Second, if you insert or delete in the middle of a sequence, that changes all of the following indices.

You can solve the first problem in two ways: either modify the sequence while iterating a copy, or build a new copy while iterating the original.

If you go with the former (mutating) solution, you can usually solve the second problem by iterating the copy backward. If the index at which you're deleting or inserting is the same one you're iterating, this is guaranteed to be safe, because it will only touch *later* indices, which you've already iterated through.

If you go with the latter solution, it automatically solves the second problem.

---

As a side note, the easiest way to iterate over a sequence in Python is to do it directly, rather than building a `range(len())` and then indexing. If you need the index as well, you can get it with `enumerate`.

---

Anyway, what you seem to be trying to do is to remove any column whose header value contains any of the badColumns names, right? Let's rewrite that as a non-mutating function that builds a new table without those columns.

```
def isBadColumn(text):
    for badText in badColumns:
        if badText in text:
            return True

badIndices = set()
for idx, header in enumerate(values[0]):
    if isBadColumn(header):
        badIndices(idx)

newValues = []
for row in values:
    newRow = []
    for idx, col in enumerate(row):
        if idx not in badIndices:
            newRow.append(col)
    newValues.append(newRow)

values = newValues
```

---

But all of those explicit `for` loops can be easily turned into comprehensions, so the whole thing reduces to this:

```
badIndices = {idx for idx, header in enumerate(values[0])
              if any(badText in header for badText in badColumns)}
values = [[col for idx, col in row if idx not in badIndices] for row in values]
```

---

If you need to do it by mutating `values` in-place (e.g., because some other code has a reference to `values` and has to see it changing), here's an equivalent:

```
# all of the code to get badIndices from above

for rowidx, row in reversed(enumerate(values)):
    for colidx, col in reversed(enumerate(row)):
        if colidx in badIndices:
            del values[rowidx][colidx]
```

---

Meanwhile, you might want to consider a different data structure in the first place. For example, if you stored each row as an `dict` (or `OrderedDict`, if you need to preserve column order) instead of a `list`, you could just do this:

```
badHeaders = {header for header in values[0]
              if any(badText in header for badText in badColumns)}
```

Then either build a new copy:

```
values = [{header: value for header, value in row.items() 
           if header not in badColumns}
          for row in values]
```

Or mutate in place:

```
for row in values:
    for header in badHeaders:
        del row[header]
```

---

*This is not quite true—you can replace individual values, and replace slices with equal-length slices. But you can't insert or delete elements, or replace slices with different-sized slices, and you're trying to delete.

Comment: do you know of any good tutorials on comprehensions?  i see them often and the syntax makes no sense to me.

Comment: @avorum: I don't know of anything better than what's in the official tutorial, so if that didn't help… I wrote something up quickly [here](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/comprehensions-for-dummies.html); let me know if it helps.